# Fitting generalized linear model with covariate

Tags: generalized-linear-model, spss, modeling, ancova

In our experimental design, we are assessing the effect of TMS on decision making. Our data is not normally distributed because our assesment test results in mean count data (ultimatum game). Besides, even randomized the previous test decisions are different across subjects as it is not possible to equalize in our case. I would prefer to rely on ANCOVA with pretest scores as covariate if they were normally distributed (not sure). But I decided to use a generalized linear model (GENLIN procedure in SPSS) instead, and use the binomial distribution with log link (as there is also too many zeros in the data set with a high variance) in SPSS.

My question is, can I use the pretest score as covariate, posttest as dependent and group as factors for GENLIN as we do it within the ANCOVA framework in many randomized trials in psychology?

Comment: What you call GLZ is actually known as a GLM :) (fixed in my edits) Could you indicate what you mean by "equalize"; when you speak about "normally distributed" scores, do you refer to the response variable or the covariate?

Comment: General - izing the Linear Model

 

The Generalized Linear Model is an extension of the General Linear Model to include response variables that follow any probability distribution in the exponential family of distributions. The exponential family includes such useful distributions as the Normal, Binomial, Poisson, Multinomial, Gamma, Negative Binomial, and others.

Comment: As seen I am talking about GLZ intead of GLM, so my qoestion is in pre-post test experimental designs, can we use pretest as covariate as we do in GLM analysisi also in GLZ analysis. :), so they are different ;)

Comment: http://userwww.sfsu.edu/~efc/classes/biol710/Glz/Generalized%20Linear%20Models.htm

Comment: Ok you mean GLM as general linear model (aka linear model). Never seen GLZ, though.

Comment: There indeed exist some confusion with abbreviations. SPSS calls (general) linear model procedure GLM, and generalized linear model procedure GENLIN. For the sake of clarity between users of different programs, I'd recommend abbreviations LM and GZLM, and never use "GLM" at all.

Comment: @cumhur, I slightly edited your question, please check if everything is OK for you.

Comment: I had a discussion about that distinction with people working in neuroimaging (where GLM refers to [tag:linear-model], the same terminology being used in dedicated statistical packages, e.g. [SPM](http://www.fil.ion.ucl.ac.uk/spm/)). It doesn't make sense to me if we refer to the literature (I can think of Nelder and McCullagh's book, for example) or even [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_linear_model). Why not calling mixed-effects models with logit link function `GLIMMIX` in this case?

Comment: @cumhur, since your question is specifically about SPSS I recommend rewriting your question so that the first sentence, and perhaps the title itself, makes that clear. SPSS is not the most popular statistical package among users of this site.

Comment: @MichaelBishop I don't think we need to explicitly refer to SPSS *in the title* as we already have a tag pointing to that software.

Comment: Can you explain (spellout) TSM?